# Should I put the dollar amount I receive from an award on my CV?

Tags: resume

I've been fortunate to receive many awards as a student doing post-secondary education. They have ranged in amount from $1000 to $17500+. 
**Should I put the dollar amount I receive from an award on my CV?** Would this differ on a professional resume? This document would be used to find work as a engineering professional in Canadian industry.

I have found these answers:

- Only include monetary amounts if they're awarded as funding grants
- Don't include monetary amounts since they are easily accessible online and if they're not public they shouldn't be
- Include it to show the gravity of the award you were presented

Comment: I don't see why the dollar value would be relevant to a prospective employer.

Comment: I would not put the dollar amount, as a potential employer that would be irrelevant to me on a CV.  However I would not be shy about mentioning it in a face to face interview.

Comment: What is the goal of your CV? Academic jobs? Industry jobs? People in each care about _very_ different thins generally. Also, what country are you in? Some countries use CVs vs resumes very differently.

Comment: @enderland Update the question to reflect your mentioned points.

Comment: What kind of professional?

Comment: Don't put the amount of the award, but the name of it, together with the time and the reason for the award.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### State WHY they are important instead

Although the monetary value appears to act as a measure of the award's value, it really isn't that good of an indicator as the amount is influenced not only by the award's value to the people giving it, but also their ability to finance it (i.e. a poor organization may not be able to give a lot of money for a very impressive award).

Thus, it really doesn't communicate the true value of the award.

Instead of using a monetary amount,  describe WHY the award is important - especially from the point-of-view of your intended audience.

EXAMPLE:

Instead of:

Receipient of the XYZ award ($17,500)

Use:

Receipient of the prestigious XYZ award for mastery/achievement/whatever in ABC.  This award is given out to the top 1% of ABC practitioners in the country each year.